# Add multiple Layer files in subdirectories to mxd using python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers

I have more than 300 layer files located in many sub-Folders and sub-sub-Folders. All Sub Folders are located in one large directory.I read [Use python to add layers to TOC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35693/use-python-to-add-layers-to-toc?rq=1)
and I try, with arcpy, to detect all the layers and add them to mxd. 
Is it possible?

Comment: i use arcview 10.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work with ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 or above, you can use the [arcpy.da.Walk()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Walk/018w00000023000000/) function:

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r"C:\directory"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Map.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="Layer")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)))

mxd.save()
```

Comment: i get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\desktop\python.py", line 13, in <module>
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 49, in AddLayer
    assert isinstance(add_layer, Layer)
AssertionError

Comment: There was an error in my script, sorry - I've updated it.