# Load multiple layers into multiple maps - python

Tags: arcpy, layers

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
#import string

env.workspace = r"G:\GIS"
mxds = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
lyrs = arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr")

for maps in mxds:
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxds, "Layers")[0]

    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df ,lyrs ,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

    maps.save()

del mxds, maps, df, lyrs
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not going to work for these reasons:

1. You need to add  a wildcard "*" to ".mxd" and ".lyr" so that these return something (lines 3 and 4)
2. You referenced "mxds" instead of "maps" on line 6, and it needs to be referenced as a arcpy.mapping.MapDocument because you need to save later.
3. You need to nest the add each layer in a loop (line 8)
4. You need to save the changes to the MapDocument object, not the mxd name (line 11)

Credit to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35693/use-python-to-add-layers-to-toc) on adding layers.

Try this fix:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"G:\GIS" 
mxds = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
lyrs = arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr")
for maps in mxds:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(maps)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    for layer in lyrs:
        addlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df ,addlayer ,"AUTO_ARRANGE")
    mxd.save()
```