# Writing Python Code to create a Median tool in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am attempting to write the code for a toll in Python that will effectively:

- access the city data and load it, if it isn't already in the list of layers
- get a country name from the user and access just the cities inside that country
- calculate the median POP_RANK of all cities in that country and report the median to the user

I am fairly new to Python, as this is all have so far.

```
import arcpy as ARCPY

def medianCalculation():

    mxd = ARCPY.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = ARCPY.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd) [0]
    country = ARCPY.GetParameter(0)
    countryCursor = ARCPY.da.SearchCursor("cities", ["CNTRY_NAME", "POP_RANK"])
    POPDict = {}
    for country in countryCursor:
```

Comment: You might have missed a piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to look into some Help pages.

- [Add the layer to the TOC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35693/use-python-to-add-layers-to-toc).
- [Get parameter (country name) as text](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000047000000).
- Get your cities into an array with [arcpy.da.SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) and do simple math with Python.