# Issue with arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management in tool

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have created a python toolbox that creates separate layers based on unique field values within a feature layer.  For some reason `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management` will create the layer but will not add it to the TOC even after using `RefreshTOC()`.  I used the same tool in the python interpreter and it adds the created layer to the TOC.

The layer doesn't need to be written to disk or saved permanently; I wanted to leave the saving up to the user.  Any thoughts on why there is a difference and how to get the layer added to the TOC?

**EDIT**

```
    ws = arcpy.env.workspace
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    data_frame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    layer = parameters[0].valueAsText #GPFeature Layer
    field = parameters[1].valueAsText #field name

    seach_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer)
    lfields = arcpy.ListFields(seach_layer.dataSource)

    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(layer, fields=field)
    #get they field type to use in query
    ftype = None
    for f in lfields:
        if f.name == field:
            ftype = f.type
    # get values for unique list
    value_list = []
    for row in rows:
        value = row.getValue(field)
        value_list.append(value)

    unique = set(value_list)
    len_list = len(unique)

    try:
        for name in unique:
            if ftype in ['Float','Double','SmallInteger']:
                where_clause = "\"%s\"=%s" %(field, name)
            else:
                where_clause = "\"%s\"='%s'" %(field, name)

            temp = r"%s_temp_%s" %(layer, field)

            # make a feature layer to an "outfile" that's in memory
            # add to TOC and leave up to user to save if they want
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer, temp,
                                              where_clause)

    except Exception as e:
        arcpy.AddError(e)
```

Comment: Do you have the output of MFL set as a parameter on the tool? Without an output, nothing is going to be added.

Comment: I set the output in the script so that `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer, temp,
                                                  where_clause)`.  `temp` is just a string and so the layer is stored in memory I believe.  The documentation for the tool says the feature layer is created and is temporary which is what I'm wanting to get, but the feature layer doesn't appear.

Comment: You'll probably need to add your script to the issue above to better understand the issue

Comment: If thats the full script, its what I thought. You dont have any parameters (`arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, temp)`. See this [help link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35693/use-python-to-add-layers-to-toc

Comment: Also under ArcMap Geoprocessing Options, "Add results of geoprocessing operations to the display"

Comment: @klewis Thanks.  I have looked at this post before but isn't using `arcpy.mapping.Layer` and arcpy.mapping.AddLayer` redundent since MakeFeatureLayer is supposed to add the Feature Layer? @KHibma Thanks also.  Your'e saying that I need to add another parameter as a derived output then set that name to temp?  I assumed I could pass a name directly into the MakeLayer.

Comment: After you MakefeatureLayer, add the layer to TOC, arcpy.Mapping.addLayer, then refreshTOC.

Comment: @mECH yes, derived output parameter. Only 'parameters' will get added to the ToC. Params are the driving mechanism to having the tool interact with the map.

Comment: @KHibma your solution did indeed work and add the layers to the ToC.  Thanks!  If you write it as an answer I'd be happy to mark this as solved.  As a note I do seem to suffer from a memory problem with only a few layers added; I'm going to try **klewis** solution to see if it works/helps with the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with tools, both models and scripts, the output is only added to the ToC if the particular output is a parameter. Parameters control interaction between the tool and the map.

In a script, use something like the following to set the output

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer, temp, where_clause)
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, temp)
```

This [Setting script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm) help explains parameters in more detail